# MySQL order by rand() performance issue

Tags: mysql, database

I have a rather inefficient MySQL query that has been working OK until recently as the database has grown in size. I am trying to select a random record using the ORDER BY RAND() syntax, but it is extremely slow (30+ seconds) and causes issues with my PHP script. Is there a more efficient way to write this query?

```
    SELECT * FROM accountcampaign, accounts WHERE 
    accountcampaign.status='ACTIVE' 
    AND accountcampaign.dateLocked IS NULL
    AND accountcampaign.campaignID='1' 
    AND ( (accountcampaign.lockedIPAddress IS NULL)  
          OR (accountcampaign.lockedIPAddress='') 
        ) 
    AND ( (accountcampaign.dateLastEntry IS NULL) 
          OR (DATE(accountcampaign.dateLastEntry) < DATE(NOW())) 
        ) 
    ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't want to use `ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1` : it will generate one random number for every row in your table.

You should try using 2 queries :

- the first one count the number of rows in your table
- then in PHP you generate a random number between 0 and this count
- then the second query get this row only

[More here](http://www.titov.net/2005/09/21/do-not-use-order-by-rand-or-how-to-get-random-rows-from-table/)

Comment: So this select statement is in a loop, and in each iteration, a user account is selected that hasn't been processed yet today. In the loop, some business logic is done and the user is marked as having been processed today once completed, so as the loop continues, the user isn't selected again. This loop continues until all users have been processed in random order.

I'm concerned about bullet points #1 and #2 because #1 doesn't account for the fact that once the user account has been processed,  it shouldn't be selected again while the loop continues until completion. Any suggestions?